# Typographic Animation (walking letters)

Tags: animation, rigging

So I'm pretty new to blender and even watching multiple tutorials I couldn't quite find a way to do what I want. I want to make an animated gif for my site that is my name "walking".

The image explains a little better. However when I rig this it deforms the mesh letter, what I want is the letter follow the "bone" but without bending and warping.

Makes sense? Can I assign each letter do a different bone?

[image]

Comment: if you don't want any deformation, don't use the With Automatic Weight option, instead select the letter, shift select the armature, switch to Pose mode, select the bone and Ctrl P > Bone. But your armature is not correct, bone should switch direction and you should use IK constraints to move them

Comment: Thanks. I tried doing the IK thing (exactly like every tutorial I've seen) but the leg just moves upwards for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

*moonboots's answer in image ...*

- Select a letter, *Shift* select the *Armature*
- Switch to *Pose* mode, select a bone and *Parent to* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> > **Bone**

[image]

(Walk downloaded from Mixamo. I just added a keyframe of rest pose on frame zero, to let letters parent on straight bone pose.)

[image]